# Place footer below taller of two overlapping elements in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a block of text that goes on top of a picture. Then below this there is a footer. But the text comes from a database, so sometimes the text is taller than the picture and sometimes shorter. I want the footer to come below the "whole thing" in either case.

Like this -- imagine the XXX's are the picture

Scenario 1:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXX  Short XXXX
XXXX  text  XXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

-- Footer --
```

Scenario 2:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXX  Long  XXXX
XXXX  text  XXXX
XXXX  runs  XXXX
      past
      the
      picture.

-- Footer --
```

It's easy enough to put the text on top of the picture with `position: absolute` for one or the other. But then the footer gets positioned without regard to the absolute element.

At the moment I've got two different versions of the screen, one where the picture is static and the text is absolute, for cases where I expect the text to be longer; and one where the text is static and the picture is absolute, for cases where the text is longer. This works, but only because I know what data is in the database today. I could have the program examine the text, but I have no way to know how tall it will lay out without knowing the size of the window the user sets for his browser, not to mention font sizes, etc.

Maybe `position: absolute` isn't the right way to do this?

- Update *

Someone suggested I make a fiddle. I was about to, but I see Adam B Smith made one that illustrates my problem very well: http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/EgLKV/6183/

That fiddle looks great if the text is taller than the image. Now delete a bunch of text so that the text is shorter than the image, and you see the footer overlaps the image.

Comment: Do you have a sample in jsfidle/plunker?

Comment: Here is a good example of his issue https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/rh6w934n/

Comment: What image? `img`tag , `background-image` on a div? You should provide a fiddle.

Comment: @akinuri RE: What image? Right now the image is an img tag inside a div. If displaying the image some other way will make it work, I'm happy to change that! I don't think it would work as a background-image because, to the best of my knowledge, there's no way to make a background image control the size of an element.

Comment: @Jay Is the size of the image fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this one will do it for you http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/EgLKV/6185/

lol

```
#container{min-height: 400px;}
#image
{    
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-9999;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
#text
{
    z-index:9999;
    width: 200px;  
    color:red;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;

}
.footer {
    background:#ffab62;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;

    z-index:9999;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: I believe Adam Smith's answer here and Akinuri's answer are essentially the same. I'll upvote both and give Adam the "selected" check just to reward him for making two tries at it. :-) These rely on assuming that you know the height of the picture, which I don't quite. I have a max-width: 100% on the picture to insure it fits on the screen. Still, if I set the container size to the maximum size of the picture, then if the picture is less, I get some blank space, but blank space is better than the footer overlapping other elements, so it's not a perfect solution, but it's pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size of the image, and set the container's size same as the image, it does work.

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 250px;
    height: 193px;
}
.container img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.container span {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    display: table;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.footer {
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://albanyvisitors.com/WpContents/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/200px-Big-Lake-Big-Sky-Mt-Washington-by-Bill-Origer-2015-photo-contest.jpg" />
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
</div>
<div class="footer">foooooooter</div>

<br>
    
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://albanyvisitors.com/WpContents/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/200px-Big-Lake-Big-Sky-Mt-Washington-by-Bill-Origer-2015-photo-contest.jpg" />
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</div>
<div class="footer">foooooooter</div>
```